# How can I change the font color in a groupbox when I disable the groupbox

Tags: c#, winforms, groupbox

I am using a Groupbox in c# and at first, it is Enabled.

when I use `Groupbox1.Enabled = false`, it's fore color (and everythings' forecolor which is in it) change to default black. and even the command `label1.Forecolor = Color.White` does not work. (Which `label1` is in the `Groupbox1`).
when I *Enable* `Groupbox`, it fixes. But I want it to be White whether `Groupbox1` is enabled or disabled.

Comment: WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET WebForms? ASP.NET MVC? Silverlight?

Comment: I am using Windows Form

Comment: Try to enable label1 after disabling GroupBox

Comment: I Tried this way just now. but it didn't work.

Comment: Yes. It worked. First I placed Label in position I wanted and then Put Groupbox on it and send GroupBox to back. then it worked. because it's not a part of Groupbox and it does not disable with it. Thank you. But I like to find a way not to do this. because I put label to put a name for Groupbox and I filled groupbox name by "". but I prefered not to use a label just for putting on top of a groupbox and I liked to use filed of "Name" of Groupbox. Anyway, It worked. Thanks.

Comment: One other  way to do that is to use the cursor keys to move a control instead of the mouse.

Comment: I know. But when You put an object into a Groupbox, You should bring it out first. And split it from Groupbox. then do the work you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you could simply not disable the GroupBox. Instead, create a method that disables all of it's children;

```
private void DisableChildren(Control control)
{
    foreach(var child in control.Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(child.GetType != typeof(Label) && child.GetType() != typeof(GroupBox)))
    {
        if(child.HasChildren)
        {
            DisableChildren(child);
        }
        child.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

You can see I'm not disabling Labels or nested GroupBoxes.

Just use like this where you would normally disable the GroupBox;

```
DisableChildren(GroupBox1);
```

Just as a side note: The same thing happens with any container under Windows Forms (GroupBox, Panel, etc).

Comment: This is a Good Solution too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In case of WPF, put this in your XAML resources :

```
 <Style TargetType="GroupBox" x:Key="NameOfYourStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Apply the style to your GroupBox and the job will be done.

```
<GroupBox Style="{StaticResource NameOfYOurStyle}"/>
```

Dimitri

Comment: Thanks. I am using Windows Form.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the fore color of the disabled controls cannot be set in the `WinForms` world. Instead, the disabled fore color is calculated from the `BackColor`

From the `Label.OnPaint` (by Reflector):

```
if (base.Enabled)
{
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, this.Text, this.Font, r, nearestColor, flags);
}
else
{
    Color foreColor = TextRenderer.DisabledTextColor(this.BackColor);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, this.Text, this.Font, r, foreColor, flags);
}
```

However, you can implement a custom `Label` class like this:

```
public class MyLabel : Label
{
    private const ContentAlignment anyBottom = ContentAlignment.BottomRight | ContentAlignment.BottomCenter | ContentAlignment.BottomLeft;
    private const ContentAlignment anyMiddle = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight | ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter | ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
    private const ContentAlignment anyRight = ContentAlignment.BottomRight | ContentAlignment.MiddleRight | ContentAlignment.TopRight;
    private const ContentAlignment anyCenter = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter | ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter | ContentAlignment.TopCenter;

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // drawing the label regularly
        if (Enabled)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            return;
        }

        // drawing the background
        Rectangle backRect = new Rectangle(ClientRectangle.X - 1, ClientRectangle.Y - 1, ClientRectangle.Width + 1, ClientRectangle.Height + 1);
        if (BackColor != Color.Transparent)
        {
            using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(BackColor))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, backRect);
            }
        }

        // drawing the image
        Image image = Image;
        if (image != null)
        {
            Region oldClip = e.Graphics.Clip;
            Rectangle imageBounds = CalcImageRenderBounds(image, ClientRectangle, RtlTranslateAlignment(ImageAlign));
            e.Graphics.IntersectClip(imageBounds);
            try
            {
                DrawImage(e.Graphics, image, ClientRectangle, RtlTranslateAlignment(ImageAlign));
            }
            finally
            {
                e.Graphics.Clip = oldClip;
            }
        }

        // drawing the Text
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(ClientRectangle.X + Padding.Left, ClientRectangle.Y + Padding.Top, ClientRectangle.Width - Padding.Horizontal, ClientRectangle.Height - Padding.Vertical);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, Font, rect, ForeColor, image == null ? BackColor : Color.Transparent, GetFormatFlags());
    }

    private TextFormatFlags GetFormatFlags()
    {
        TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding | TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl | TextFormatFlags.WordBreak;

        bool isRtl = RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Yes;
        var contentAlignment = TextAlign;
        if (isRtl)
            contentAlignment = RtlTranslateContent(contentAlignment);

        if ((contentAlignment & anyBottom) != 0)
            flags |= TextFormatFlags.Bottom;
        else if ((contentAlignment & anyMiddle) != 0)
            flags |= TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter;
        else
            flags |= TextFormatFlags.Top;

        if ((contentAlignment & anyRight) != 0)
            flags |= TextFormatFlags.Right;
        else if ((contentAlignment & anyCenter) != 0)
            flags |= TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter;
        else
            flags |= TextFormatFlags.Left;

        if (AutoEllipsis)
            flags |= TextFormatFlags.WordEllipsis | TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis;
        if (isRtl)
            flags |= TextFormatFlags.RightToLeft;
        if (UseMnemonic)
            flags |= TextFormatFlags.NoPrefix;
        if (!ShowKeyboardCues)
            flags |= TextFormatFlags.HidePrefix;

        return flags;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I got my answer in your first sentence. I thought I was doing somewhere wrong. but I realized that it is not my fault and it's because of the logic of programming behind it.

Answer (score 1):

I manually changed the Groupbox's foreColor which affected the Text properties, font like so:

Changed all occurrences of Enabled false with -

```
            grpGeneral.ForeColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
            grpGeneral.Enabled = false;
```

And changed all occurrences of Enabled true with -

```
            grpGeneral.Enabled = true;
            grpGeneral.ForeColor = SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText;
```